# Buildfire Meta Tag 'disableTheme' not working

Tags: buildfire

I made a custom plugin for our Buildfire app and even when I put  into the index page of our app and the general theme of the app still gets injected in. Below are photos:

[What its supposed to look like]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjmZ7.png

[What it currently looks like]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMfNu.png

[Meta tag in the live div on the buildfire console]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASLo2.png

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are allowed to use only one buildfire meta tag. Try something like this

```
<meta name="buildfire" content="disableTheme,disableBootstrap">
```

Comment: This did not work, see screenshot: [link] https://ibb.co/dt2NPJf
Before this, I copy and pasted the exact tag you responded with and got the same result.